# how to connect windows azure virtual machine with ubuntu system correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, azure-connect

i have created a virtual machine with ubuntu installed, and tring to connect to it with PuTTY, but after typing account and password, the command window output the following:

```
Access Denied
```

i am novice for windows azure and ubuntu, any help?

Comment: Not familiar with ubuntu on azure, but I guess it would be the same as any other vm platform. Are you trying to login with `root` or a normal user? `root` is disabled out of the box as far as I know.

Comment: i am using a normal user that i provided when i creating that vm, how can i login with root?

Comment: You do not generally need to login as `root` since you can do everything through `sudo`. However, if you want to enable `root` you can go `sudo passwd root`. When logging in with the normal user, are you sure that you have the right username and password combination? Both username and passwords are case sensitive when logging in through `SSH`. You question would probably be better suited for [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/), which also is a stackexchange q&a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigating 3 hours, i find what i am trying is on the bad way. so i put down my conclusion:

there are 2 ways in azure portal for creating windows azure virtual machine: 1.called **"QUICK CREATE"**, in this way we will not provide its ssh key for authentication; just use a default aka fixed user name: azureuser, and the password you provide. 2.**"FROM GALLERY"**, you have to provide ssh key for authentication for login successfully.

I created my vm via the **"QUICK CREATE"**, but i am using the wrong user name(it should be "azureuser") to login, so show me the message **"Access Denied"**.

hope helped.